# jScrollPane inside jQuery Accordion, works but is invisible!

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using the following plugins. 
*jQuery accordion*: 
http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/ 
*jScrollPane*:
// Can't post a second hyperlink

Both work correct, but I can't get jScrollPane to work inside the accordion.

```
            <div class="basic" style="float:left;"  id="list1a"> <!-- Accordion -->
            <a><p class="text" style="font-size:18px; color:#848484;">&#187NEWS</p></a>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="scroll-pane"> <!-- jScrollPane -->
                    <p style="font-size: 11px;">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc...
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- And a few other elements -->
```

When I place div.content outside of the accordion it works correctly. But inside the accordion the scrollbar is invisible. It's still there, I can scroll it, I can grab onto it, but I can't see it. I maybe thought I had to reinitialise the scrollpane when the accordion opens again after it has been closed, but it still works correctly so I'm now guessing it's a CSS problem? I'm not highly experienced with Javascript but I can image they clash somehow.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Got it! It was a CSS problem indeed. The background color of the accordion was set to white, and somehow it overlapped the scrollpane. Set it to transparant now, everything works fine!